# Where I can get iOS UI element templates (graphics) for designing a realistic static mockup?

Tags: ios, ipad, user-interface

I'm trying to create a mockup of an ipad app and I want it to be completely realistic.

This will be static so I just need graphical UI elements.

Comment: The answers aren't terribly subjective. If someone posts a source that has pictures that look to the Average User like iOS then that's a satisfactory answer..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Keynotopia has Hi Res and wireframe elements for iPhone, iPad, and other mobile devices.  This link is for the iOS 7 iPad items: http://keynotopia.com/ipad-prototyping/

Comment: As a side note to this, if you use Keynotopia and Keynote, you can make somewhat interactive mockups to help convey your app ideas.  Pretty clever really.

Comment: Was looking for ios6 (should have specified) but that's a good answer for anyone else [read: everyone in 1 year] looking for 7.

Comment: It includes iOS 6 templates too!  The screen shots are further down in the list.  Best of luck.

Comment: Does it include blank version so I can add my own text?

Comment: I believe you can change the text on most of the components.

Answer (score 1):

I think Teehan+Lax have a very nice psd [here](http://www.teehanlax.com/tools/).

Comment: gah! You beat me to it.

Comment: I did see that one but I was looking for something with BLANK UI elements so I can add my own text overlay.  And iOS6 is just fine.